# JavaScript: Code issuse

Tags: javascript

I have this JS code, in which i would like to call x var and set value. But  it is not working: When the function returns the value of x, the result is `undefined`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var myvar={
FirstL:function(){
    var x='hello world';
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="click me"  onclick="document.write(myvar.FirstL().x);" >
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because your function isn't returning anything?

Comment: whene return I get undefined restlt ?

Answer (score 0):

`var x` is a private variable and you cannot use it outside the function scope, you may just return the x and call your method:

```
var myvar={
FirstL:function(){
    var x='hello world';
    return x;
}
}
```

In html attribute:

```
onclick="document.write(myvar.FirstL());"//FirstL() returns the 'x'
```

---

Suggestion:

Don't use `document.write()` you may google for its alternative.

Comment: how i can set a value to x whene I'm call FirstL Function

Comment: if you want the syntax to match exactly you would need to return `return { x: x };` then the call looks like `document.write(myvar.FirstL().x);`